# C# Windows Forms application does not display localDB data

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms, localdb

I developed a C# Windows Forms and localDB application (Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 8.1). I've created an installer.

I installed the application on another PC running Windows 7, before that, I installed .NET Framework 4.6 on that computer. The installation runs well; but when I launch the application, the information from database is not displayed.

The comboboxes, datagridviews, etc are empty and it is supposed to show data from local DB.

If I install the application in the computer where I developed it, everything works well.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is SqlServer installed on another computer?

Comment: yes, it is an older version (2008)... is it necessary to be installed?

Comment: Is it the same name of the database in the new PC ?

Comment: and if you are using integrated security=True; make sure the Windows user has privileges in Sql Server.

Comment: Sorry but I think I'm getting confused... what I developed is a c# winforms application with a "portable" sql server database where it is not necessary for users to install sql server. The installer includes de *.MDF file... when users installs the application, the data of the database is not displayed........ and yes, the database has the same name.

Comment: You still need to install Sql Server client.

Comment: thanks for aswering... I already installed sql server client and reinstall the winform application, but nothing different happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
As Wowo Ot said, I needed to install Sql client in the client PC, but I also had to install localDB.msi and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

try adding some code to capture the exceptions and display. There could be many reasons
a. User permissions on db
b. Incorrect connection string
c. etc..

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering... I did your recomedation and I get the exception: "the underlying provider failed on open"